# Generic parts library for Altium Designer 15?

Tags: altium

I am just started using the Altium Designer 15 on 30 trial.
I realize the library is empty by default. And as a trial user it seems I don't get access to the Altium Vault (cloud based part library?).

I don't need anything specific, just the usual 0805 SMD resistors, caps, op-amps, some headers.

Is there a generic part library that I can use?

They have a page for [old, frozen library for Altium 10](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Download+Libraries). Not sure this is a good start, as it's old!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altium should install a minimum set of items into the following location: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Altium\AD15.1B\Library
(replace AD15.1B with your version)

Do you get access to the forums with the trial version (forums.live.altium.com)?

Comment: Great found it! I have enough to get me started! I tried to access the forum, but I keep getting a message saying a representative will be in touch after I enter my info =(.